# i am creating a simple google map application; i am facing errors given below

Tags: android, eclipse

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/mvMain"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          />
```

Menifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prashant.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >

        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="6587000" />
 <!--           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />   -->


     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857): Process: com.prashant.maps, PID: 2857
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prashant.maps/com.prashant.maps.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at com.prashant.maps.Main.onCreate(Main.java:22)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     ... 10 more
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:618)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     ... 19 more
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.prashant.maps-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:604)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     ... 23 more
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):         ... 25 more
02-28 19:56:58.052: E/AndroidRuntime(2857):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Answer (score 0):

Check these things:

- Provide Google Play Services Version and Your API maps key in your AndroidManifest. Seems like you have only Google Play Services meta-data (and providing in a hardcoded way -- that's not good)

  ```
  <application> 
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

      <meta-data 
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/> 
  </application>
  ```
- Include Google Play Services in the 'build.gradle' of your application.

  ```
  ...
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
  }
  ```

If you're still getting problems, try changing 'android:name' to 'class' in the fragment tag:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: still getting this error:   02-28 23:01:58.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 23:01:58.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1914): Process: com.prashant.maps, PID: 1914
02-28 23:01:58.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prashant.maps/com.prashant.maps.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment